# changing permissions of Read-only file system in linux

Tags: linux, file-permissions, dd

i use this command to make a bootable flash disk of linux mint

```
 sudo dd if=~/Desktop/linuxmint.iso of=/dev/sdx oflag=direct  bs=1048576
```

it's work, but now my flash disk is lock and i can't change file on it
now this file is on flash disk

```
dr-xr-xr-x 1 ahmad ahmad  2048 May  13 02:24 boot
dr-xr-xr-x 1 ahmad ahmad  2048 May  13 02:24 casper
dr-xr-xr-x 1 ahmad ahmad  2048 May  13 02:23 dists
dr-xr-xr-x 1 ahmad ahmad  2048 May  13 02:24 EFI
dr-xr-xr-x 1 ahmad ahmad  8192 May  13 02:24 isolinux
-r--r--r-- 1 ahmad ahmad 21495 May  13 02:24 MD5SUMS
dr-xr-xr-x 1 ahmad ahmad  2048 May  13 02:23 pool
dr-xr-xr-x 1 ahmad ahmad  2048 May  13 02:24 preseed
-r--r--r-- 1 ahmad ahmad   220 May  13 02:24 README.diskdefines
```

i try `sudo chmod 777 *` on my disk but it don't work

Comment: You can't change permissions on a ISO 9660 filesystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

However you can write your resulting `/dev/sdX` device. After you are done with `dd` as you mentioned you can mount `/dev/sdX` as RW when you didn't boot you system from this device.

- If you have already mounted this device, and it is Read Only, you can remount it in RW by

`sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdX` , but it works only if you are not running your `/` system from this partition. Check the partitions mounted with `mount -l`. Well, actually running OS from this device you will see that the file system changes that you have done can be seen during the sessionm but it's a kind of illusion, they will no be written to the disk.

- If you need to have a different data set in the iso file, you need it to mount, copy this data, modify and then make a new ISO by something like.

`mkisofs -o /tmp/cd.iso /tmp/directory/` To make an ISO from files on your hard drive.

- If you need to make a bootable USB drive from your image: choose either `Startup Disk Creator` or [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/). And if you want to make changes to be saved after you worked in OS on you USB drive you need to tell about `persistence` to these programs at the disc creation stage.

in `Startup Disk Creator`:

[image]

[image]

in `UNetbootin`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't change permissions nor alter any data in an ISO 9660 filesystem since it's read-only by nature. Despite this you can opt to somehow update data on it if your record format supports multiple sessions. The only thing to consider is that can't change it the normal way in the UNIX filesystem. You may find this [howto](http://www.math.nyu.edu/aml/CDwrite.html) helpful. Directly creating a new ISO image than having multiple sessions may also be a better practice. The only thing is that it's complicated when you're creating an isolinux-bootable one.